# Custom Sitecore dialog broken with upgrade to v6.6

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I recently updated our site from Sitecore 6.3.1 to the latest 6.6 release.  Now my custom dialog app is giving me a "Page Not Found" error.

It lives in sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs along with all of the built-in Sitecore tools accessible in Content Editor: Publishing, CopyTo, Clone, etc.  These are working fine.

Did 6.6 change the way these paths are resolved?  Do I need to add my custom application name to a config somewhere?  All files are in place... and the code is definitely up to date.  The class declaration is `public class LanguagePopUpForm : DialogForm`.  Is DialogForm still valid here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue can be caused by the layout not being updated properly or linked correctly.

Try to open the content editor, navigate to the `sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/YourDialog` item and check on the `Presentation` tab if what are the `Layout Details` of your application.

If the link there is not broken, open the layout item of this application and see what is the value of the `Control` or `Path` fields. Then try to find the file in your web application files and if it exists, open the proper file in the browser.

Comment: Thank you, you nailed it. Deleting my superfluously dumb comments that could only confuse someone else looking for this answer.